# OpenCV: Concurrent GetSubImage to extract a portion of an image

Tags: c#, opencv, crop, roi

I've implemented a `GetSubImage` function in order to extract a portion of an image. I use `SetROI`, `Copy`, and `ResetROI`. But this not works when Parallel Tasks are using the same image because of the `SetROI` is not parallelizable.

Any other way to extract portion of an image that can run concurrent?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a temporary matrix header that only points to a part of the matrix. Then you can use the `copyTo()` member function on that header. Example in C++:

```
Mat GetSubImage(const Mat& source, const Rect &region)
{
    Mat dest;
    Mat roi(source, region);
    roi.copyTo(dest);
    return dest;
}
```

This way, neither the data nor the header of `source` are affected by the operation, so you can perform it concurrently.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm using OpenCvSharp library and the CvMat class does not have thins constructor...

Comment: What are you talking about? It is right there: http://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp/html/bf9a14ed-6ebb-704b-2372-7e104ef77196.htm

Answer (score 1):

Finally, to extract a portion of an image, I'm using this function. Used on C# and with the OpenCVSharp wraper:

```
    static public IplImage GetSubImage(IplImage ipl, CvRect r)
    {
        CvMat submat;
        CvMat mat = ipl.GetSubRect(out submat, r);
        IplImage i = new IplImage(r.Width, r.Height, ipl.Depth, ipl.NChannels);
        Cv.Copy(mat, i);

        mat.Dispose();
        submat.Dispose();           

        return i;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and posting the solution! That's the spirit! I can only suggest to you to switch to the modern API though. It was introduced in OpenCV 2.0 and it is 3.1 now already.

Comment: Which API? I'm using this https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp and it's very complete and perfect for me.

Comment: Yes OpenCVSharp comes with two APIs. The old OpenCV 1.x one and the new OpenCV 2.x, 3.x one. See https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp#usage Do you See CvMat, IplImage there? No! Because it is the new API they are using in their example. Mat == new, CvMat == old.

Comment: Ok great! Using 2.4 version here. I'll take a look to the 3.x version but it's not easy to update libraries and api's when you have soft all over the world.

Comment: The new API is already part of 2.4. You just need to stop using cvMat and start using Mat..